# Laravel5.6 - override a vendor view

Tags: php, laravel, view, overriding, vendor

I try to make my own version of a vendor blade template.
I dont want to extends the controller with the reference of the view.

So in my AppServiceProvider I add this line:

```
// Custom views for passport
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/views/oauth/passport', 'passport');
```

I created a file named authorize.blade.php in /resources/views/oauth/passport

In the vendor controller method we can see this:

```
return $this->response->view('passport::authorize');
```

The problem is when I call the vendor controller method it loads his version of authorize.blade.php. I would like mine to be loaded and I expected the new line I added to AppServiceProvider to do that.

Comment: Under https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#issuing-access-tokens *Approving The Request* there's instructions on how to extract the vendor views for customization. This is assuming you are referring to Laravel Passport

Comment: @apokryfos I managed this but my problem is that I can't customize the place where I put my passport views. I thought I can manage this with loadViewsFrom but it seems it doesn't work. If I want to make it work I have to put the file in /resources/vendor/passport but I want the file to stand in another place. Can I do this?

Comment: I doubt you can. I guess you can just strip them down and have them include other views from other places though.

Answer (score 2):

Passport comes with VUE components and views you need to publish first to override them. From the [Laravel Passport page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport):

"*If you would like to customize the authorization approval screen, you may publish Passport's views using the `vendor:publish` Artisan command.*"

All you need to do is run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views` and the vendor views will be place in `resources/views/vendor/passport`, where you can edit them.

Comment: I try this and it works but I would like to place my version of passport views in a precise location. How can I achieve this? Is it possible? I thought it is the purpose of loadViewsFrom method called in AppServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views` this will copy the views to your views folder for you to change.

Answer (score 0):

> So in my AppServiceProvider I add this line:
>
> // Custom views for passport
>       $this->loadViewsFrom(**DIR**.'/../../resources/views/oauth/passport',
>   'passport');

You can use this option only by placing it in registry () instead of boot(). And then you can use your Views regardless of whether they were published in Vendor or not

Answer (score 0):

It's actually as simple as creating a `resources/views/vendor/{namespace}` directory, then dropping in your view file to replace/override the vendors'.

Check out the base `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider`
[image]

All that means is that the view will be resolved if there is a matching view file in the `resources/views/vendor/$namespace` directory

## NOTE

The package you're replacing views for needs to call the `loadViewsFrom` method to register it's views, otherwise, they won't notice the custom files.

The passport package does this here: [PassportServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/eb78ec6c192a01fbbe76dd427630a5e500e2486a/src/PassportServiceProvider.php#L74C9-L74C9)
[image]